# Two indices deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, deadlock

I have a table in SQL Server (Azure SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE Commands
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Body nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    Priority int NOT NULL,
    DeliveryDate datetime NOT NULL,
    VisibleFrom datetime NULL,
)
```

The table also has an index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PriorityAndDate ON Commands (Priority DESC, DeliveryDate ASC)
```

Then I have two sessions.

**Session 1**

```
WITH command AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM Commands q
    WHERE q.DeliveryDate <= @CurrentDate
      AND (q.VisibleFrom IS NULL OR q.VisibleFrom <= @CurrentDate)
    ORDER BY q.Priority DESC, q.DeliveryDate
)
UPDATE command SET command.VisibleFrom = DATEADD(SECOND, @LeaseTimeout, @CurrentDate)
OUTPUT inserted.Id,
       inserted.Body
```

**Session 2**

```
DELETE FROM Commands WHERE Id = @Id
```

In some circumstances a deadlock occurs:

1. Session 1 locks IX_PriorityAndDate index (U lock).
2. Session 2 locks PK_Commands index (X lock).
3. Session 1 blocks on waiting PK_Commands (acquiring U lock).
4. Session 2 blocks on waiting IX_PriorityAndDate (acquiring X lock).

**How to resolve this deadlock?**

Comment: Isn't it a logic bug that the same command is being updated and deleted at the same time? Or does the index access on IX_PriorityAndDate read multiple rows? In that case, why is there an UPDLOCK hint? Remove it and use READ COMMITTED or snapshot isolation.

Comment: It's not a logic bug, these queries are executed in different contexts for different rows. The same deadlock occurs with or without WITH(UPDLOCK) hint. I'll remove it to make question more clear.

Comment: What isolation level do those statements run under?

Comment: Check the execution plan to make sure the index is being used as expected (i.e. no scan/sort).

Comment: @usr, it's Read Committed.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP, what do you mean no scan/sort? There is index scan operation (IX_PriorityAndDate) in the plan of the first query. Why shouldn't it be here?

Comment: If the plan shows an index scan followed by a sort, then the index is not being used efficiently and every row in the table will be touched.  Large scans are a recipe for deadlocks.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP, you are right. There is a scan because of predicate with VisibleFrom column. Alexander provides a good answer to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have the key lookup deadlock

Try to use the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PriorityAndDate
  ON Commands (Priority DESC, DeliveryDate ASC) INCLUDE(VisibleFrom)
```

Or try to create a new index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PriorityAndDate
  ON Commands(DeliveryDate, VisibleFrom) INCLUDE(Priority)
```